# Authorization Error || Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

this error keeps showing I don't why ! I changed the URI many times and it still showing

[image]

**This what my Google Cloud Console looks like:**

[image]

**My auth.js:**

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }))

router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', 
  { failureRedirect: '/register' }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
)
```

And in the PassportJs function I entered *"/auth/google/callback"* to `callbackURL:`

The route is `app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);` and I'm using two ports one for client (3000) and one for API (4000), now in Authorized redirect URIs which port should I use !!

Comment: When being redirected to google, which URL is being passed as the redirect_uri query param? For the port: Do you expect being redirected to your frontend or to your backend? For the path: I am seeing three different configurations, "/google/callback", "/api/auth" and "/auth/google/callback". Which one is which?

Comment: There is a button on the frontend which its function goes >> const google = () => {
    window.open("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google", "_self");
  }; << after tapping on this button it redirects to the Google login page with the above error

Comment: Make sure your running https